# I am trying to get this file to run after scheduled time, however it only ran once

Tags: java

I am trying to get this audio file to run after a given time.
I know I need to have everything reset I am just stumped on how exactly to go about doing this .

How do I get this to run more than once on a set schedule??

```
   Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
                TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            audioClip.open(audioStream);
                        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        audioClip.start();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click OK to Stop Music");
                        audioClip.stop();
                        t.cancel();
                    }
                };

        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 500, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the [Timer cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel--) method inside your `TimerTask` run method. From [Timer cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel--) documentation:

> Note that calling this method from within the run method of a timer
> task that was invoked by this timer absolutely guarantees that the
> ongoing task execution is the last task execution that will ever be
> performed by this timer.

Then this works as expected, so if you want more than one execution remove the `t.cancel()` from your TimerTask `run` method.